# Linux code/text editor with specific features (open-source)

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, software-development, text-editor

Please recommend a Linux (Debian / Ubuntu / Mint) text/code editor that meets the following feature requirements:

1. Able to load a 15MB file with word wrap enabled in under 2 seconds on moderate hardware (mid-range processor, SSD, plenty of RAM).  If this is not possible, ability to use a command line option to open the editor in a separate instance without word wrap and then load a 14MB file in under 2 seconds.
2. Able to jump to pre-defined sections of a file (one way to accomplish this is if the application has macro capabilities, and allows one to record a Find operation and assign it to a keyboard shortcut).
3. Regex find & replace.
4. Delete duplicate line functionality (while ignoring empty lines).
5. Spell-checker.
6. Open source.
7. Gratis.
8. GUI

What I've tried:

- xed: does not have #1, #2, #4
- Geany: does not have #1 or #2 (a plugin can remove duplicate lines, but it also removes every blank line except the first blank line in the file!)
- CudaText: does not have #2 or #4, and the Linux Flatpak that I tried was a hot mess. It forced some sort of old Windows cursor, would not adjust colours according to settings, and had other issues.

What I didn't try, but researched:

- Sublime Text: does not meet #6 or #7
- gedit: does not appear to meet #4, even with plugins

Comment: Sounds like vim should solve this

Comment: #4 sounds very specific - what problem are you trying to solve?